# How to protect Only Month and year of date in Powerbuilder

Tags: date, powerbuilder

How to protect only Month and Year of a date in Powerbuilder so user can only edit day of the date?

Comment: Questions on stackoverflow must show what you have tried and why it didnt work.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: You did not specified if you need that in a datawindow or in another visual object / window, but I think it is not possible as is. Either use a specific field to enter a day then combine it to the rest of the date, or use a validation code that can reject or replace the month+year part.

Answer (score 0):

As comments suggest, this reads more like a user requirement than a technical question (e.g. lack of mention of what type of control is involved), but if this were my requirement, I'd try one of these (user exercise to figure out which ones would actually work; it's not *my* requirement *grin*).

**EditChanged**: I'd put a date EditMask on a DataWindow (remember external DataWindows; it's a common misconception to think that controls on DataWindows have to be tied to a database column), and code the EditChanged to revert the year and month back to their set values if they've been changed. (I'd consider this pretty aggravating for the user, but it's possible)

**Day field**: Make the year and month StaticText, and make the day only an editable field. Edit, EditMask or EditMask with spin control would be appropriate for this (spin gives you control over the range with minimal scripting).

**Custom control**: Grab the source code for a dropdown calendar (PFC comes to mind), and customize it to disable the navigation between years and months.

Good luck,

Terry